# jboss standalone-full.xml ,min-pool-size and max-pool-size issue

Tags: jboss, rhel7, rundeck

need a help, i have a java application which is running on jboss -6. recently we got a requirement to keep our min-pool-size and max-pool-size  same, along with prefill value should be "true'.

```
<pool>
<min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
<prefill>true</prefill>
</pool>
```

By default our standalone-full.xml has following datasource:

```
 <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/<datasourcename>" pool-name="<datasourcename>" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://<dbhostip>:<port>/<dbdetailsForconnection></connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <max-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
```

we have requirement to set pool size like  below:

```
<pool>
<min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
<prefill>true</prefill>
</pool>
```

but every time when we make changes , our war files failed to get deployed.  We are getting following error:

IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
When we define our connection pool setting like below:
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

Approaches I tried:
*remove datasource from jboss-cli and add datasource again
*directly edit standalone-full.xml
*after every change :reload it.
*do the deployment and then edit xml ,reload afterward
*before deployment ,edit, reload

Solution: I have two solution to make it work :

1. min  pool should be less than max

```
    <pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size> 
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
```

2. Remove profill, as it will take min pool size as default to fill up the connection

```
    <pool>
    <min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size> 
    </pool>
```

but these solution are against the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of head scratching, finally i have resolved this issue by increasing max connection limit in my db serveri.e mysql .
after set max_connection limit. it start working